# How to build SigLockedDustAllowanceOutput in iota client python?

Tags: python, client-library

I read the [doc](https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/specs/index.html#message) and was able to send transaction by `message()`. But I couldn't find how to add output
as `SigLockedDustAllowanceOutput`. It seems the default is `SigLockedSingleOutput`. The following the code I used to build tx. Please help, thanks.

```
for to_address in to_address_list:
    outputs_list.append({
        'address': to_address,
        'amount': amount
    })
client = iota_client.Client()
message = client.message(
    seed=seed,
    outputs=outputs_list
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the [python reference](https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/python/api_reference.html#high-level-apis) instead of the specification reference (your link), you will see that message also takes `dust_allowance_outputs` in addition to `outputs`.

Alternatively (this is the route I was going) you can search the source code of the [python bindings](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/python/native) where they call the Rust `with_cust_allowance_output` method and you will see that it iterates over those exact `dust_allowance_outputs`. Of course this requires that you know how the Rust API is building dust allowance outputs, so probably the first way is the way to go.

Regardless, use `dust_allowance_outputs` instead of `outputs` and you should be good to go.